# Incompatible Declaration in Implementation file in C++

Tags: c++, declaration

I have a couple incompatible declarations in my implementation file for my lab that I cant figure out why. I'm still learning C++ but I cant see what this problem is. Basically all the program is supposed to do is when its run is to spit out a message at the end stating the Welcome to the grade book to and state the class for the grade book along with the Teacher. However my set and get statements in my Implementation file wont allow me to compile because of a incompatibility. I could use a few tips Thank you.

Here is my code for all three files:

Header -

```
#include <string> 

class GradeBook
{
public:
    explicit GradeBook(std::string);
    void setCourseName(std::string);
    std::string getCourseName() const;
    void displayMessage()const;
    void setInstructorName(std::string);
    std::string getInstructorName() const;
private:
    std::string courseName;
    std::string instructorName;  
};
```

Implementation file -

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"
using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook(string name): courseName(name)

{

}

void GradeBook::setCourseName() const
{
    courseName = name;
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName() const 
{
    return courseName;
}

void GradeBook::setInstructorName() const
{
    instructorName = name;
}

string GradeBook::getInstructorName() const
{
    return instructorName;
}
void GradeBook::displayMessage() const
{
    cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "with"     << getInstructorName << "!" << endl;
}
```

Main file-

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    GradeBook courseName("COP2224: Intro To C++ Programming");
    GradeBook instructorName("Heidi Gentry Kolen");
}
```

Comment: Where are the error messages

Comment: If you had taken the time to reduce the code to a minimal example, you would have found the error yourself.

Comment: The funny thing is this is minimal, from a starting point in learning this. Yes it can be simplified but i need to learn more.

Comment: [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AverageJoe: no, it's not minimal ... here's the minimal version you should be able to arrive at before posting a new question to SO: `class GradeBook { public: void setCourseName(std::string name) const { courseName = name; } private: std::string courseName; }` all in the header file. In fact, this small program might have shown you what you needed just by itself.

Comment: I say all that not to be mean, but to tell you one of the most important things I know about programming: **the compiler is your best teacher**. Write small programs, and make sure they _build_ and _run_, then make them bigger. I've been a professional programmer for over twenty years, and I still do this everyday ... if you were to add the word _test_ to the _build_ and _run_ advice, this would be one of my number one things that I tell beginning programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void setCourseName(std::string);         // declaration in .h
void GradeBook::setCourseName() const    // implementation in .cpp
```

```
void setInstructorName(std::string);      // declaration in .h
void GradeBook::setInstructorName() const // implementation in .cpp
```

See the difference?  Your implementations are missing the `name` parameter and have trailing `const` modifiers.  You need to correct those mistakes:

```
void GradeBook::setCourseName(std::string name)
{
    courseName = name;
}

void GradeBook::setInstructorName(std::string name)
{
    instructorName = name;
}
```

The signature of an implementation must match the signature of its declaration.

Comment: Hmm i totally didnt catch that. I appreciate it.  Like i said i am still learning but Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
void GradeBook::setCourseName() const
{
    courseName = name;
}
```

That's wrong.

Not only you missed to give it the same signature as from the declaration

```
void setCourseName(std::string);
```

It would never work as `const` member function, unless `courseName` is declared as `mutable`. Also `name` isn't declared in this context.

I'd guess that's all simply a typo.

Answer (score 1):

declaration is:

```
void setCourseName(std::string);
```

while in definition

```
void GradeBook::setCourseName() const
```

which is incorrect

correct definition should be

```
void GradeBook::setCourseName(std::string name)
```

Comment: Was about to comment, but you got it: now that you've removed `const`, as in other answers, I'm upvoting.

Comment: And if you downvoted QuestionAndAnswer for it, maybe you could remove it.

Comment: @JohnCastleman: I have not downvoted QuestionAndAnswer for it.

Comment: ok good ... his answer wasn't right, but wasn't so wrong it needed a downvote, IMHO.

Answer (score -4):

You don't need an explicit keyword before GradeBook's constructor.
Delete const modifier after setInstructorName and SetCourseName in implementation file.

Comment: how to removal of const will help to solve the problem

Comment: Removing `const` *is* definitely part of the solution (*I'm* not one of the downvoters), but `explicit` keyword is definitely in there for a reason (which I think is actually why you're getting downvotes)

Comment: @Sumeet, Set methods designed to change class's field value. Const keyword restricts any changing in class. If Set methods in this example mean something else, then, yes, my answer is useless.

Comment: @JohnCastleman, Yes, explicit keyword is not the main reason. It was just by the way.

Comment: @Summet, Oh... I see now. I don't noticed args list. My fault.

Comment: @QuestionAndAnswer: Agree set method used to change the value but that changed value should be provided in function arguments without which it will not work.